# ¿Mejores prácticas para inicializar una variable dentro de un bucle?

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo necesidad de inicializar una nueva variable dentro de un bucle y lo suelo hacer de esta manera:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT DISTINCT(`mes`) as mes
FROM tabla where 1
ORDER BY mes ASC;
");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($result as $row){
$mes = $row -> mes;

    echo '<hr>Agente: '. $agent_country = $pdo->query("
    SELECT agent_id FROM genuine_agents where agent_month = '".$mes."'
    ")->fetchColumn();

    echo '<br/>Target: '. $target = $pdo->query("
    SELECT target_target FROM targets where target_month = '".$mes."'
    and target_report = 'Genuine'
    ")->fetchColumn();

}
```

Me pregunto si es la forma correcta de hacerlo y si no es mejor utilizar `while` en este caso y porqué.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando tú usas `$pdo->fetch` estás recorriendo un cursor, y por eso el ciclo while:

```
while( $row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  ... cosas
}
```

Esto significa "*mientras lo que hay dentro del while sea verdad, que siga el bucle*". Y lo que hay dentro del while será verdad mientras el cursor tenga más resultado que entregarle a `$row`. Como no tienes idea de cuántos resultados pueda entregar el cursor, el while es un ciclo no determinístico.

Cuando tú usas `$pdo->fetchAll`, lo que recibes es un **array**, y un array se recorre con un `forEach` (o con un for, si quieres hacerlo a la antigua). No tiene sentido usar un while para recorrer un array, porque ya conoces su dimensión de antemano.

```
$resultado = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($resultado as $row) {
  ... cosas
}
```

En resumen, la diferencia está en decir: "*ejecuta un loop mientras queden resultados en este cursor cuyo contenido ignoro*", y decir: "*ejecuta un loop entre todos los elementos de este array cuyo contenido ya conozco*".

Answer (score 1):

### Antes de abordar una respuesta

Antes de responder a tu pregunta quiero señalar lo siguiente:

Normalmente cuando se trata de leer los resultados de una consulta hecha a la base de datos hay varias formas de obtener y leer dichos resultados.

En el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) aparecen explicados los diferentes métodos.

Estás usando el método `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` para "almacenar" tus resultados. Dice el Manual de PHP:

> `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`: **devuelve un objeto anónimo** con nombres de propiedades
>   que se corresponden a los nombres de las columnas devueltas en el
>   conjunto de resultados.

Es decir, si usamos `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` en este código de ejemplo:

```
$gsent = $gbd->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$gsent->execute();
print("PDO::FETCH_OBJ: ");
print("Devolver la siguiente fila como un objeto anónimo con nombres de columna como propiedades\n");
$result = $gsent->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print $result->name;
print("\n");
```

Devolverá algo como esto:

```
PDO::FETCH_OBJ: Devolver la siguiente fila como un objeto anónimo con nombres de columna como propiedades
kiwi
```

En realidad, en el conjunto de resultados `$result` habrá algo como esto:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'id' => '104',
   'name' => 'kiwi',
   'colour' => 'verde',
))
```

### Ahora abordamos una respuesta a tu pregunta

Es correcto inicializar una variable dentro de un bucle, a no ser que sea una variable que vas a ir concatenando dentro del mismo. En ese caso es  mejor inicializarla fuera del bucle, mucho más si dentro de él habrá condiciones del tipo `if then else`, `switch case`... de esa manera te aseguras que la variable se inicializará cada vez que entre dentro del bucle. En cambio, si piensas usar la variable una sola vez en cada ocurrencia, ningún problema en inicializarla dentro.

Ya que hablas en tu pregunta de **mejores prácticas**, me permito indicarte que a lo mejor no estás aplicando la mejor práctica en la manera en que obtienes tus resultados. Me refiero a almacenarlos usando `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

#### ¿Realmente necesitas un objeto anónimo?

Si **realmente** necesitas que tus resultados sean almacenados en un **objeto anónimo**, entonces sí `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` es la mejor opción.

Si usas `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` (como se muestra en el ejmplo) se accede a cada columna del resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
$result->nombre_de_columna;
```

En el ejemplo que pones, la variable $mes sería algo así:

```
$mes= $result->mes;
```

#### ¿No necesitas un objeto anónimo?

Por el contrario, si lo que necesitas es leer o imprimir tus resultados, existen mejores métodos, como por ejemplo `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

> `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`: devuelve un array indexado por los nombres de las
>   columnas del conjunto de resultados.

En el caso de `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` el resultado se mostraría así:

```
  Array ( [0] =>    Array ( [mes] => Enero )
          [1] =>    Array ( [mes] => Febrero )
          [2] =>    Array ( [mes] => Marzo ) ... etc
        )
```

Y accederías a cada elemento a través de un bucle for, tal y como lo tienes en tu código, pero indicando en cada $row el nombre del índice:

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $mes = $row ["mes"];
    //... resto del código
 }
```

En cada fila podría haber otras columnas de tus resultados y accederías igual, llamándolas por el nombre que tienen antes de `=>` dentro de cada array.

Esta forma de acceder es más clara y eficaz que `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, sobre todo si no necesitas manejar el objeto anónimo creado.